# BlackScreen after launching NativeScript application on Android

Tags: android, nativescript

I wrote a NativeScript app and wanted to test it on Android. It works properly on ios, but whenever I run "tns run android" I get a BlackScreen where a "Copy to Clipboard"-Button is displayed.

The screen and my emulators where I tested it can be seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adyee.jpg

I am not sure what went wrong, can anyone relate to this behaviour?